# How to override environment path variable to call curl from custom path instead of system32 path?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe, environment-variables, curl

I have a path for folder containing curl.exe file (`C:\My\Custom\Directory\`) added to Path Environment Variable. The problem is that when I call `curl` from command line, it runs another curl executable than the intended one. When I traced which executable was running using Process Explorer, I found it in `C:\Windows\System32\` (may be installed after the new Windows Update). The problem with this is that this executable doesn't support some features I use.

What I need to do is to override `curl` to call curl.exe from `C:\My\Custom\Directory\` instead of calling it from `C:\Windows\System32\`.

Notes:
I know I can use `"C:\My\Custom\Directory\curl.exe"` in command line, but I want to use `curl` only to call curl.exe from my custom directory.
Also I can't delete `C:\Windows\System32\` from the Path variable because it contains other important executable, and I think I can't.

Comment: Put your curl directory path at the start of the PATH environment variable rather than the end.

Comment: Why not modify the order in the path to have your `C:\My\Custom\Directory\` in front. There ***is*** a curl.exe with the very last update. Fall update doesn't have it.

Answer (score 4):

> The order of %path% items matters. You can check it using `where curl.exe`

Thanks to [JosefZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3439404/josefz) and everyone commented.

Comment: If moving `C:\My\Custom\Directory` above `C:\Windows\System32` in the `PATH` order causes unintended side-effects, then another option is to use an alias `doskey curl=C:\My\Custom\Directory\curl.exe`, though it will work only from the command line, not in a batch file. The alias check precedes any `PATH` search.